# How to create a sample single-column Spark DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a sample single-column DataFrame, but the following code is not working:

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame(["10","11","13"], ("age"))

## ValueError
## ...
## ValueError: Could not parse datatype: age
```

The expected result:

```
age
10
11
13
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> the following code is not working

With single element you need a schema as type

```
spark.createDataFrame(["10","11","13"], "string").toDF("age")
```

or `DataType`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

spark.createDataFrame(["10","11","13"], StringType()).toDF("age")
```

With name elements should be tuples and schema as sequence:

```
spark.createDataFrame([("10", ), ("11", ), ("13",  )], ["age"])
```

Comment: "With single element you need a schema as type" 
This is exactly what I was missing, thank you

Comment: This helped me. It was not working because of this unusual comma was absent.

Answer (score 15):

Well .. There is some pretty easy method for creating sample dataframe in PySpark

```
>>> df = sc.parallelize([[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]).toDF()
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  2|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+
```

to create with some column names

```
>>> df1 = sc.parallelize([[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]).toDF(("a", "b", "c"))
>>> df1.show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  2|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+
```

In this way, no need to define schema too.Hope this is the simplest way

Answer (score 8):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([{"a": "x", "b": "y", "c": "3"}])
```

Output: (no need to define schema)

```
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  3|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: This is deprecated in newer Spark versions. Rather use df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a="x", b="y", c="3")])

Answer (score 5):

For pandas + pyspark users, if you've already installed pandas in the cluster, you can do this simply:

```
# create pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':['a','b','c']})

# convert to spark dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

> **Local Spark Setup**

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark

spark = (pyspark
         .sql
         .SparkSession
         .builder
         .master("local")
         .getOrCreate())
```

Answer (score 1):

See my [farsante](https://github.com/MrPowers/farsante) lib for creating a DataFrame with fake data:

```py
import farsante

df = farsante.quick_pyspark_df(['first_name', 'last_name'], 7)
df.show()
```

```
+----------+---------+
|first_name|last_name|
+----------+---------+
|     Tommy|     Hess|
|    Arthur| Melendez|
|  Clemente|    Blair|
|    Wesley|   Conrad|
|    Willis|   Dunlap|
|     Bruna|  Sellers|
|     Tonda| Schwartz|
+----------+---------+
```

Here's how to explicitly specify the schema when creating the PySpark DataFrame:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [(10,), (11,), (13,)],
  StructType([StructField("some_int", IntegerType(), True)]))

df.show()
```

```
+--------+
|some_int|
+--------+
|      10|
|      11|
|      13|
+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this -

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc) # sc is the spark context
sample = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('qwe', 23), # enter your data here
        ('rty',34),
        ('yui',56),
        ],
    ['abc', 'def'] # the row header/column labels should be entered here
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to create a DataFrame, [PySpark Create DataFrame](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/different-ways-to-create-dataframe-in-pyspark/) is one of the first steps you learn while working on PySpark

I assume you already have data, columns, and an RDD.

```
1) df = rdd.toDF()
2) df = rdd.toDF(columns) //Assigns column names
3) df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF(*columns)
4) df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
5) df = spark.createDataFrame(rowData,columns)
```

Besides these, you can find several examples on [pyspark create dataframe](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/different-ways-to-create-dataframe-in-pyspark/)