# createDataFrame (pyspark) generates a weird error (py4j error)

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I wrote these simple 4 lines of code:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spa = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spa.createDataFrame([(1,2,3)], ["count"])
```

but that createDataFrame function is generating this huge error:

> Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         3 spa = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
>         4 
>   ----> 5 spa.createDataFrame([(1,2,3)], ["count"])
>
> c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py
>   in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
>       690         else:
>       691             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
>   --> 692         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
>       693         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())
>       694         df = DataFrame(jdf, self._wrapped)
>
> c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py
>   in _to_java_object_rdd(self)    2294         """    2295         rdd =
>   self._pickled()
>   -> 2296         return self.ctx._jvm.SerDeUtil.pythonToJava(rdd._jrdd, True)    2297     2298     def countApprox(self, timeout,
>   confidence=0.95):
>
> c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py
>   in _jrdd(self)    2472
>   self._jrdd_deserializer, profiler)    2473         python_rdd =
>   self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD(self._prev_jrdd.rdd(), wrapped_func,
>   -> 2474                                              self.preservesPartitioning)    2475         self._jrdd_val =
>   python_rdd.asJavaRDD()    2476
>
> c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)    1523         answer =
>   self._gateway_client.send_command(command)    1524
>   return_value = get_return_value(
>   -> 1525             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)    1526     1527         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py
>   in deco(*a, **kw)
>        61     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py
>   in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       330                 raise Py4JError(
>       331                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
>   --> 332                     format(target_id, ".", name, value))
>       333         else:
>       334             raise Py4JError(
>
> **> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling
>   None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD. Trace: py4j.Py4JException:
>   Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD([class
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionRDD, class
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction, class java.lang.Boolean])
>   does not exist    at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
>     at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
>     at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)    at
>   py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
>     at
>   py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
>     at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)**

why is this happening? that code is literally the same as other tutorials and it works fine there...

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674311/how-to-create-a-sample-spark-dataframe-in-python and see if you are still getting error. check versions of spark once

Comment: It will be successful in spark shell or submit the job " spark-submit yourcode.py"

Answer (score -1):

Try this It's working. Place a comma after the values, while initializing.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spa = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spa.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([(1,), (2,), (3,)]), ("count",),)
```

Output:

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
+-----+
```

Hope this helps!