# PySpark how to create a single column dataframe

Tags: pyspark

Why this works:

```
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, MapType

    data = [("prod1", 1),("prod7",4)]
    schema = StructType([
         StructField('prod', StringType()),
         StructField('price', StringType())
     ])
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = schema)
    df.show()
```

But this generates an error:

```
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, MapType

    data = [("prod1"),("prod7")]
    schema = StructType([
         StructField('prod', StringType())
     ])
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = schema)
    df.show()
```

Error:

```
    TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'prod1' in type
```

Why is the error and how to create a dataframe with a single column? I am working on Databricks with Apache Spark 3.3.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a sample single-column Spark DataFrame in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674311/how-to-create-a-sample-single-column-spark-dataframe-in-python)

Comment: @PrathikKini no, the titles looks similar but the issues are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` requires a list of `tuple` (or `list`), `("prod1")` is converted to `"prod1"`, which is a **string type**.
You need to add `,` to make it a **single-element tuple**.

```
data = [("prod1",), ("prod7",)]
```