# Writing to UserMetadata Field During Table Creation

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, delta-lake

When I run the following code in my DataBricks environment, the initial save does **not** write "Initial Commit" to the userMetaData field; however, the two following "append" operations respectively write "Added James Brown" and "Added Joe Red, Jim Blue and Joe True" to userMetaData without issue:

```py
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674311/how-to-create-a-sample-single-column-spark-dataframe-in-python
df1 = sc.parallelize([["Brown", "John"], ["Green", "John"]]).toDF(("LastName", "FirstName"))
df2 = sc.parallelize([["Brown", "James"]]).toDF(("LastName", "FirstName"))
df3 = sc.parallelize([["Red", "Joe"], ["Blue", "Jim"], ["True", "Joe"]]).toDF(("LastName", "FirstName"))


# https://bigdataprogrammers.com/write-dataframe-to-delta-table-in-databricks-with-append-mode/
# https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/custom-metadata.html#language-python
tableName = "myCatalog.mySchema.metaDataTest"
df1.write.format("delta").option("userMetadata", "Initial Commit").saveAsTable(tableName)
df2.write.mode("append").format("delta").option("userMetadata", "Added James Brown").saveAsTable(tableName)
df3.write.mode("append").format("delta").option("userMetadata", "Added Joe Red, Jim Blue and Joe True").saveAsTable(tableName)
```

Why is my initial table creation via df1 not writing "Initial Commit" to the userMetadata field?

[image: Select all Rows from metaDataTest Table]
[image: describe history metaDataTest]

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula - Yes, I used Azure DataBricks when running the above code in a notebook.

Comment: I have tried with databricks non - unity catalog version. I am able to get the Initial Commit.

Comment: For the initial version I used DataBricks with Unity Catalog, but the same thing also seems to happen in Azure Synapse Analytics with raw Spark. The good news is your solution seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set "**Initial Commit**" as the metadata for **version 0**, you should explicitly create the Delta table with that metadata before appending data.

write to a Delta table by running the `history` command
Know more about [Retrieve Delta table history](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#id3)

Try the below approach:

```
df1.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("userMetadata", "Initial Commit").save(tablePath)
```

In the above code I have used the `.mode ("overwrite")`
[image]

[image]

Comment: I got your solution to work, but I had to use saveAsTable instead of save.